# Export datatable to pdf with more then 100 columns in dt

Tags: c#, itext

while exporting a datatable with 135 columns to pdf it shows square boxes instead of data

following method is used to export to pdf but the pdf generated was not showing the data if number of columns is more then 100 rather it was showing square boxes.

```
public void ExportToPdf(string ReportName)
{
    DataTable dt;
    if (tabmain.ActiveTabIndex == 0)
    {
        dt = GetQueryData(IsSessionSource, 0, 0).DataSet.Tables[0];
    }
    else
    {
        dt = GetQueryData(IsSessionSource, 0, 0).DataSet.Tables[1];
    }
    Document document = new Document();
    //PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create));
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, Response.OutputStream);
    document.Open();
    iTextSharp.text.Font font5 = iTextSharp.text.FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 5);
    iTextSharp.text.Font myFont = iTextSharp.text.FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.TIMES_BOLD, 8, BaseColor.BLUE);
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(dt.Columns.Count);
    PdfPRow row = null;

    table.WidthPercentage = 100;
    int iCol = 0;
    string colname = "";
    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Products"));

    cell.Colspan = dt.Columns.Count;

    foreach (DataColumn c in dt.Columns)
    {
        table.AddCell(new Phrase(c.ColumnName, myFont));
    }
    int i = dt.Columns.Count;
    foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
    {
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            {
                table.AddCell(new Phrase(r[j].ToString(), font5));
            }
        }
    } 
    document.Add(table);
    document.Close();
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename= " + ReportName + ".pdf");
    Response.End();
}
```

Comment: What is your question? Obviously, your columns become pretty narrow when you have that many on a page that isn't wide enough to hold them all, but _what_ do you want to do about it?

Comment: i want to export that to pdf.is there any way to do that..??

Comment: Sure, you are doing it. I assume you may want to spread your table over multiple pages in some way or another, but it is up to you to think about that. Once you know _what_ you want to do, then you can think about _how_ you can do it. If you get stuck in that process, feel free to ask for help.

Comment: Thanks Kris for your suggestion.yes i m able to export to pdf but it was not showing data instead it was showing boxes.so is it possible to export that much columns into pdf bcoz i have googled a lot but i found nothing regarding this .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you are simply using a font which is too small to fit on the page. Too much stuff on a single page. 
The easiest way i can think of to do what you want to do: send the datatable to an excel file instead and then manually save-as pdf.

If that is not an option, you can try changing the page size of the pdf. there is a decent article here:

http://www.dotnetfox.com/articles/how-to-change-pdf-document-page-size-in-Asp-Net-with-C-Sharp-usng-itextsharp-1024.aspx

inside that article above, it quotes the following:

```
Rectangle method:

      Document document = new Document(new Rectangle(200f, 300f)); 
PageSize method: 
      Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 20f, 20f, 20f, 20f);

PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create));

    document.Open();
    document.Add(new Paragraph("Welcome to dotnetfox"));
    document.Close();
```

Hope that helps. Cheers.

Comment: I agree with kicking the page size up, the default is 8.5"x11" I think. `PageSize.B0` is the largest built-in named one as far as I know but you can always use the `Rectangle` constructor as @metinoheat noted, too.